# How do I stop getting 'note' messages after compiling a cpp file?

Tags: c++, mingw

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    vector<int> first;
    vector<int> second(4, 100);
    vector<int> third(second.begin(), second.end());
    vector<int> fourth(third);

    int myArr[] = {5, 4, 3, 2};
    vector<int> fifth(myArr, myArr + sizeof(myArr)/sizeof(int));


    //cout << "hello world";
}
```

I know the error but I get this 'note' message like 50 times and messes up the command prompt. I'll include a screen shot. Why is it happening and what can I do to make my command prompt look non confusing.

[notes and errors after compiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qogov.png)

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the notes?  They are giving you helpful information.  Reading big errors like that can seem daunting at first but once you understand how to read error messages you can get some very valuable information our of those notes.

Comment: `grep` is your friend.

Comment: @NathanOliver I know it helps to read and understand the messages. But for two error messages I got like 50 of these note messages messing up the prompt. I wish there's a way to get only the error messages. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Redirect the output to a file. Then your prompt will remain pristine.

Answer (score 0):

afaik you cant stop that. What you have there is a so called linker error. Basically you tried to do something that was not intended and it shows you in which library code is causing the linker error. When you see this you can be pretty sure that you used something you included in an unintended way..

It turns up if you call an included member function wrongly or if the function(overloaded << operator) is not there.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-linker-error-in-C

Comment: This is not a linker error.  It is a compiler error.

Comment: @jaaq Thanks for the info though I wish I could get only the error messages with out the linker notes.